# How to import tippy.js into an html page with webpack 4?

Tags: javascript, webpack, tooltip, webpack-4, tippyjs

Per the tippy.js git hub page I installed it with npm:

```
npm i tippy.js
```

Now I have a .js source file that's used for a webpack 4 html page that gets output to my ./dist folder, but I don't know how to import it; my other option is just to include it from the CDN but that doesn't seem very webpackesque

Also I'm using ES6 via babel-loader stage-0; so how exactly do I import that in so it's included with my bundle?

Shouldn't the CSS for tippy need to be imported as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found it [here](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/)

```
import tippy from 'tippy.js'
```

and for CSS it's

```
import 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.css'
```