# How to require tippy.js in Webpack 3.6?

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix, tippyjs

I'm using Laravel Mix, which uses Webpack 3.6, and I'm trying to install https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/.

My SCSS is probably working fine via `@import "../../../../node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.css";`.

However, at the top of my javascript file, I have this, which doesn't work:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var webcast_helper = require('webcast_helper');
var moment = require('moment');
import tippy from 'tippy.js';
```

I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

**How can I import Tippy.js in a way that works with this Webpack approach?**

<sub>([How to import tippy.js into an html page with webpack 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547456/how-to-import-tippy-js-into-an-html-page-with-webpack-4) obviously doesn't work for me.)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import tippy from 'tippy.js'` uses the ESM version (the `"module"` field in package.json).

For TippyJs 5.0.1 and Webpack 4, try:  `const tippy = require('tippy.js').default;`

To use the UMD version (supports CJS)

However I don't recommend using CJS version because treeshaking doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that, and it seems to work for 2.6.0 but not 3.2.0, as I mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53404391/470749

Comment: How about `require('tippy.js/dist/tippy.js')`. To include CSS as well: `require('tippy.js/dist/tippy.all.js')`

Comment: I'm now back trying to get Tippy working (and I might as well try to get v5 working instead of 2.6), but I haven't figured out how to get it working when required via Webpack. Any ideas? I'm excited about your library and really hope it can work for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated your answer, upvoted it, and accepted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```js
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.tippy = require('tippy.js').default;
```

Comment: Ahh I see this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Line below works for me on webpack 3.3.0

`const tippy = require('tippy.js/umd/index.all.js')`

Got this from the [tippy.js website](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/getting-started/#package): 
[image]

** **Note:** You willl also need to include a css loader in your *webpack.config.js* if the css is used

Comment: I'm finally back to this question (wanting to try Tippy again), and this answer looked promising, but now Tippy is at version 5, and I can't find instructions about how to get it to work with Webpack.

Answer (score -1):

**I'd *prefer* to accept an answer from someone who can show me how to get 3.2.0 to work.**

I was able to get an *older* version ([2.6.0](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v2/index.html)) to work (partially).

`npm install tippy.js@2.6.0`

In my file:

```
const tippy = require('tippy.js');
tippy($(inputRangeEl).get(0), {
    content: "Rewind by clicking anywhere on this red slider",
    arrow: true,
    duration: [0, 1000], // Array [show, hide]
    followCursor: "horizontal",
    size: 'large',
    animation: 'scale'
});
```

**But the tooltips unfortunately never appear on touch devices (such as iPhone) and I don't know why.**

I'm trying to have a tooltip on `<input type="range" id="position" name="position" step="1" min="0" max="1" value="1" title="Rewind by clicking anywhere on this red slider"/>`.